# Save a stream of data in a column of PostgreSQL using TypeORM

Tags: javascript, postgresql, stream, typeorm

I need to save a big csv file content in a column of my table. I have tried using buffer, but it is returning `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`, is it a way to save it using stream, i.e, store just part of the csv in memory, not the whole csv data?

Storing the whole CSV in memory:

```
let content = [];
   let bufferContent = null;
   await (new Promise(resolve => {
     notificationRequest.usersStream
       .on(‘data’, function(buffer) {
         content.push(buffer);
       })
       .on(‘end’, function() {
         bufferContent = Buffer.concat(content);
         resolve();
       });
   }));
```

Trying to save the buffer in DB:

```
this.dbRepository.save(bufferContent);
```

Gives me the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

TypeORM Entity

```
@Column({ type: ‘bytea’, nullable: true})
 csvBuffer?: Buffer;
```

PS: If the file is small the code above works perfectly.